# SAP BusinessObjects Universe Designer: cannot add c# reference designer.exe

Tags: c#, business-objects

I'm trying to compile a simple program that uses the SAP Business Objects 4.0 universe designer API. I basically follow this simple guide:
[Getting Started with Designer SDK in C#](http://bukhantsov.org/2011/08/getting-started-with-designer-sdk/)

The main point of the guide is that I have to add a reference to a COM resource `designer.exe`, which is listed in the VS project's COM resources. I add it and get message:

> A reference to 'BusinessObjects Designer 14.0 Object Library' could not be added.
>
> Could not register the ActiveX type library 'C:..\win32_x86\designer.exe'.

My computer is Win7 64 bit, the project is set to x86. It does not work in VS2010express and in VS2012Express.

I've been struggling with this for a day now, it seems to work on a colleague's computer.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem on my machine, using Windows 8, I used the regtlibv12.exe program to register designer.tlb.

My system did not originally have a copy of this program, as explained in this article:

[What happened to regtlibv12?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769590/what-happened-to-regtlibv12)

Mentioned in the article above, some users have been able to obtain this utility when installing the .Net framework, and it is missing when the operating system comes with the .Net framework preinstalled.

I used a copy of regtlibv12.exe bundled with another product on my system called [InstallAware](http://www.installaware.com) 16.

Answer (score 1):

Is the type library `C:\..\win32_x86\Designer.tlb` listed in the COM references? If not, open the Universe Design Tool (UDT). Opening UDT will generate the `.tlb` file.

Try adding the `C:\..\win32_x86\designer.exe` reference after `.tlb` file is listed in COM references.

Comment: Unfortunately, running udt did not change anything. Specifically, running it, inclusive logging successfully to a remote server, does not create designer.tlb