# How to register a legacy typelib (.tlb) on Windows 10?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, regasm, typelib

I have Visual Studio 2015 running on Windows 10 and need to register a legacy type lib (.tlb). From the posts I've found, `regtlibv12.exe` is the tool for this. However, I can't find it under `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\` or anywhere else for that matter. Does anyone know how to register `.tlb` if `regtlibv12.exe` doesn't exist?

I've tried `regasm /tlb:path` but I get errors saying the path cannot be read.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What Is a XY question?

Comment: This post covers the case of the missing regtlibv12.exe file on Windows 8 in detail and should apply to Windows 10 as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12770517/1339945.

Comment: I don't think this really is a duplicate of the question. Anyway I got round it in a completely different way. Open Access or Excel create a VBA module. Tools->References. Browse to your tlb and select it. It wil register it so anything can use it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the old regtlibv12.exe from an older machine.

I upgraded to Windows 10 and lost the function but found it here:
C:\Windows.old\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

works fine.